# Xamarin Switch Toggled event : get bound item of list

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding

Latest Xamarin on Mac as of writing:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Summary}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Reporter}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="Micro"  />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Start}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Result}" Toggled="Handle_Toggled"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

How do I get the bound item to a Switch control in a ListView. The item is  in the list of items bound to the ListView, provided by the ViewModel. You can 'switch' the item's toggle without selecting the row.

```
void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    // In this event handler, how do I get the bound item from the ListView?? 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, what you'd need to do, is to react to the changes of property "Result" in your item class, and keep your logic out of the Page class.
If you need to handle in the event, you can do it this way:

```
void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    var switch = sender as Switch;
    var item = switch.Parent.BindingContext as ItemViewModel;
}
```

Replace ItemViewModel by your item's type.

Comment: Thanks - understood about PropertyChangedEvent; that makes sense. In this case I need to actually pull up the item Detail page if some aspect of item is in a certain state when the Switch is toggled by the user. In my case - the 'list' of items is provided by the ViewModel, so switch.BindingContext is the actual data item record.

Comment: @Hicham How can you achieve similar result in MVVM model?

Comment: @niketan it depends on your solution, but generally it's done using two approaches:
1. two way databinding on the Switch.
2. pass the event of toggling to the ItemViewModel